# How to have textbox regular expression validation on asp.net?

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How to have TextBox regular expression validation on asp.net?

I will have to allow 3 digits and units in the text box. Decimal units should not exceed more than 2 units.

How to handle that?

```
<input  class="form-control"  id="Temperature" />
```

Comment: at most 3 digit and 2 decimals right? 3.2 is accepted right?

Comment: yes for now..  . in a good scenario. i need to put a range also

Comment: at least for now.. let me have  0.0 to  999.99

Comment: what are units?

Comment: 2 decimal units

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this regular expression, as I understood in your comment:

```
\d{1,3}\.\d{1,2}
```

Have a look at [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KI9S12/1/)

Comment: [RegularExpression(@"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,2})?$")]

Comment: I am testing that syntax.. , that doesnt give output

Comment: [RegularExpression(@"^\d{1,3}+(.\d{1,2})?$")]   - I am not able to validate this syntax

Comment: did you check the demo?

Comment: Yeah , but i have to apply that on my c#

Comment: Actual syntax : <input class="form-control" id="Temperature" pattern = "\d{1,3}\.\d{1,2}$" title="Invalid Temperature"/>